# Playing a DVD ISO on the Pi

Tags: raspbian, dvd

I need to be able to play a DVD from ISO on the Pi; the very specific presentation for which I want to use this relies on moving between chapters on the DVD.

I'd like to keep things as simple as possible and use Raspbian with OMXPlayer to achieve this.   However I can find no information on how to play a DVD ISO using OMXPlayer.  Simply entering

```
omxplayer -o hdmi presentation.iso
```

doesn't work: it just says 'Have a nice day'.

**Can anyone tell me how to get OMXPlayer to play a DVD from a .iso file?**

---

***Notes:***

1. I can play the presentation using Xine, but as Xine isn't optimised
   for the Pi's GPU it's dropping a lot of frames.  However this
   confirms that the iso itself is working.
2. I've tried using XBMC, but there's an intrusive on-screen display on
   any chapter move, and I can find no way of suppressing it.
3. The underlying aim here is to avoid the need to carry a laptop and a
   load of cables. Ideally I'd leave the pi plugged in to the back of
   the projector I use, have it put up a menu on boot which I can
   navigate with the projector remote, and cut out a good deal of setup
   time.  I'm open to alternative suggestions to achieve this;
   OMXPlayer just originally seemed likely to be the simplest option.

Comment: most video players will refuse to play .iso file, you have to extract .vob data from your DVD if you want to play it.

Comment: From Xine's front page: "2014-07-06: Release" "xine-lib 1.2.6" "Changes include video decoding and output for Raspberry Pi". So it looks like there's something very fresh on the subject. I'll be testing it as soon as I receive my codec licences :)

Comment: If Xine gets optimised for the Pi, that will be perfect for me!

Comment: Did anyone figure out the configuration necessary to get Xine to use the RPi hardware decoder?  I purchased my licenses and it's still jerky.  Looking for answers I found this question.